# how to define the file path in nodejs require('') with "../ " Notations?

Tags: node.js, path, require, filepath

I am having trouble in defining paths in nodejs.

I need to define path with some `../../` But really I don't understand how to Use this `..`  notations.

Example:

```
var core=require('../../app/server/controllers');
```

in Meanjs 0.3 which worked good.

Now I changed to Mean 0.4 where its little different folder structure Which eating my time define path.

Could anybody give some helping explanation about this dot notation regarding path defining with a single `.`?

Aim is to define the path of my `core/server/controller/core.server.controller.js` file in my custom directory  `restaurants.server.controller.js`

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: "../" means you're navigating one directory up from the folder you're currently in. "./" means that you want to reference some file in the same folder. Also, your screenshot is really small and the letters are barely visible.

Comment: @ Bidhan A  .Asper that can you pls Give the path for my aim ... as answer Please

Comment: Actually it looks good when you right click and do view image .. Could you pls Give a try that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `restaurant.server.controller.js` is in the `modules/restaurants/server/controllers` directory. `../` means go up one directory, so `../../../` (up three directories) would put you in `/modules`. Then you can find the `core.server.controller.js` by following the `core/server/controllers` directories.

So the final require you want for core is:

```
var core = require('../../../core/server/controllers/core.server.controller');
```

Comment: @ Tom Robinson var core = require('../../../core/server/controllers/core.server.controller'); this one working but is this optimized way for really ?

Comment: Could you pls define path for config in same folder pal pls?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to do it. Often if your code is grouped together sensibly then you see less of this, but it's unavoidable.

Comment: Pal could you please define one more path just for my sake plz ?

Comment: Your `config` directory is one directory higher than `modules`, so add another `../` and then go into the config directory e.g. `var config = require('../../../../config/config');`

Answer (score 3):

You Could use this  Helps for Path issue
https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Some Solutions

1). The Global

```
In your app.js:

global.__base = __dirname + '/';

In your very/far/away/module.js:

var Article = require(__base + 'app/models/article');
```

2). The Module

```
Install some module:

npm install app-module-path --save

In your app.js, before any require() calls:

require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname + '/app');

In your very/far/away/module.js:

var Article = require('models/article');
```